# HTML5 Video tag no fullscreen in frames

Tags: html, video, fullscreen, frameset

I have a simple HTML page containing a video tag. When shown outside a frame in a frameset I get a working fullscreen button on the video.
When placed inside a frame in a frameset hovever, the fullscreen button is greyed out (Chrome) or it has disappeared (FireFox and IE 11). 
Does anyone have an explanation for this - and even better a solution for me?
Any help is highly appreciated!

default.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Video in frame</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="10%, 90%">
    <frame/>
    <frame src="video.html"/> 
</frameset>
</html>
```

video.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

When showing default.html in a browser, there is no (or greyed) fullscreen button.
When showing video.html in a browser, there is a working fullscreen button.

Comment: Provide the html for both cases.

Comment: Thanks Tanveer - sample html provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<frame>` and `<frameset>` elements are deprecated for security reasons and should not be used. Instead prefer the `<iframe>` one and CSS.
But even using this, you will need to add the [`allowfullscreen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes) attribute so the video can request the browser's fullscreen mode from this iframe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Video in frame</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe allowfullscreen src="video.html"></iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

Since stacksnippet's iframe don't have this attribute themselves, we need to outsource the live example [to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c2u1ham/).

Comment: Much appreciated Kaiido! Works great!

Comment: @BirgerNiss glad it helped. You can mark this answer as accepted so the question gets off of the "in need of an answer" feed. See [the help center](/help/someone-answers)